# Unable to get correct delivery fee in Foodpanda via scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am getting delivery fee but for few restaurants, its slightly different than the one on website, say its $2.99 on website but spider is getting $3.09. I have checked latitude and longitude but its same in the url and spider. I have changed multiple values in headers and it changed the delivery fee for few restaurants but not for all. This is the sample url: https://www.foodpanda.sg/restaurants/new?lat=1.43035&lng=103.83684&vertical=restaurants and below is the code snippet:

```
api_url = 'https://disco.deliveryhero.io/listing/api/v1/pandora/vendors'
form_data = {
    'country': 'sg',
    'latitude': str(lat),
    'longitude': str(lng),
    'sort': '',
    'language_id': str(self.language_id),
    'vertical': 'restaurants',
    'include': 'characteristics',
    'dynamic_pricing': '0',
    'configuration': 'Variant1',
    'use_free_delivery_label': 'true',
    'limit': '50',
    'offset': '0'
}
headers = {
    'X-FP-API-KEY': 'volo',
    'dps-session-id': dps_session_id,
    'x-disco-client-id': 'web',
}
return scrapy.FormRequest(
    api_url,
    method='GET',
    headers=headers,
    formdata=form_data,
    meta={
        'page': page,
        'lat': lat,
        'lng': lng,
        'item_meta': item_meta,
        'start_position': start_position
    },
    callback=self.parse_search
)
```

Any clue or insight is appreciated.

Comment: maybe they are calculating in a discount that can be added based on a cookie or something...

Comment: Thought so too, but that's not the case :(